# How to Send Push notification in Ionic Framework?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, hybrid

How to send Push Notification in Android Hybrid Application using built on Ionic Framework. 
I am Newbie, Please Guide me Step by Step how to send Push notification in ionic? 
I saw a different tutorials on youtube and other websites but i am confused where to add those code which shown on these website. I have GCM Project Number (`SENDER_ID`)  but dont know where to put it. 
Please Guide In details. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://devdactic.com/ionic-push-notifications-guide/

Comment: I did same as described in this tutorial... but still I am confused and didn't get it. Or may be i am doing something wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Try using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) ? It is easy to implement and use.

Config :

```
    var push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "Your-sender-ID",
            "forceShow": true, // To show notifications on screen as well
            "iconColor": "#403782",
            "badge": "true",
            "clearBadge": "true" // To clear app badge
        },
        "ios": {
            "alert": "true",
            "badge": "true",
            "clearBadge": "true",
            "sound": "true",
            "forceShow": "true"
        },
        "windows": {}
    });
```

Device Registration :

```
    push.on('registration', function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem('pushToken', data.registrationId); // Save registration ID
    });
```

Handle Notifications

```
    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // Handle all requests here
        if (data.additionalData.$state == "mystate") {
            $state.go('app.conversations');
        }
    })
```

Comment: That's okay, someone might need this in future.